# How to send keyboard key in my application?

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard

I'm currently using `SendKeys.SendWait(text);` in C#
but `SendKeys` sending the key global and I have to activate my application and then send it. And another problem is when I type something in my keyboard (in another app) and the `SendKeys` function activates (in my app) mistakes happen.

So how can I send a message to my application regardless what application is active and what I type in my keyboard?

Comment: What is the purpose of this application, can you provide some relevant code you already have?

Comment: Well it a bot program - using webbrowser control. And i want to type message and send it. I cant do it with changing value of the input form... so i have to send keys to the application. About the code you want - there is noting to show. i just use the above function to send keys and that is it, but i want to change that function to match my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SendMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does what you want. You'll need to use it like:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const UInt32 WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
const int VK_Q = 0x51; // taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

SendMessage(handleToTheInputForm, WM_CHAR, VK_Q, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a `handle` on the other application's window so that you can bring it to focus and reliably send your keystrokes to it,

Have a look at this tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx

Comment: Yes i do that now but im saying again mistakes happen. i don't want my application to be dependent on that what application is active...